# Adding multiple vlan interfaces into bridge (ovs)

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bridge, openvswitch

I am adding multiple vlan interfaces (eth3.409, eth3.410, ...) to a bridge, furthermore I also add the eth2 interface (local network) to the bridge.

eth3 is a trunk with 13 different vlans. The bridge and all other ports are up, none of them have a IP address configured. I simply want layer 2 switching.
The bridge should be at the end an open vSwitch for traffic control.

The problem now is that if I add at least two of the eth3.x interfaces (packets do not have a vlan tag anymore) the network is not working. the clients at the end of the vlan are not reachable anymore (website does not open). I am seeing tons of arp requests (broadcast) and also replies for the gateway. Wireshark says that the arp requests have an ethernet checksum error.

If I only have the eth2 and one eth3.x interface in the bridge everything works.
I also tested the same with OVS, but it behaves the same.

I have no idea what the problem is. I guess it has something to do with the vlans. It is strange because I see the arp responses leaving the eth3.x interfaces.

I hope someone can help.

BR,
rommon

Comment: the operating system is debian 8 64Bit with latest updates installed